# Stored proc - union query syntax error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I have an issue with a dynamic query inside a sproc I have in mysql.

Now this query executes fine when I execute it directly in phpmyadmin however this seems to spring up a syntax error upon execution.

```
BEGIN
SET @sql = 'set @my_id=24;
set @rank=0;
select * from ( 
    (
     select *, @rank:=@rank+1 as x from `list_content` where `id` > @my_id order by `id`)
     union (select *, @rank:=@rank+1 as x from `list_content` where `id` < @my_id order by `id`)
    ) `list_content` WHERE `listId` = 15 limit 4';

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

I really need this to work somehow as I need to change some field names with params I pass through.

The execution error I get is ...

```
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set @rank=0;
select * from ( 
    (
     select *, @rank:=@rank+1 as x from `list_c' at line 2
```

I presume this is a limitation with a prep query if I can execute it outside of this environment with no problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mysql manual on [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) says:

> SQL syntax for prepared statements does not support multi-statements
>   (that is, multiple statements within a single string separated by ;
>   characters).

This means that you cannot have 3 statements on your prepared statement. However, the same section of the manual also says that

> A prepared statement is also global to the session.

This means that you can move the set statements outside of the prepared statement into the code of the dtored proc and the session variables will be available within the prepared statement.

Comment: Thanks for your help, im new to sprocs. Got it working in the end which is the main thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a delimiter or else the `;` will end your procedure. Like this:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE whatever_you_named_it
BEGIN
SET @sql = 'set @my_id=24;
set @rank=0;
select * from ( 
    (
     select *, @rank:=@rank+1 as x from `list_content` where `id` > @my_id order by `id`)
     union (select *, @rank:=@rank+1 as x from `list_content` where `id` < @my_id order by `id`)
    ) `list_content` WHERE `listId` = 15 limit 4';

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
//
```

Then you can set the delimiter back to `;` with

```
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have added the delimiter and I cannot save the sproc. MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//
BEGIN
SET @sql = 'set @my_id=24;
set @rank=0;
select * from ( 
 (
  sel' at line 1

Comment: Delimiter has to be set before the create procedure statement

Comment: Hmm i just deleted the sproc and ran the above and just got this - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN SET @sql = 'set @my_id=24; set @rank=0; select * from ( ( s' at line 2

Comment: @MatthewHarris you can't have a begin - end outside of a stored procedure. Pls read at least the basics before starting to write stored procedures...

Answer (score 0):

Put the variables setup into the query. see was @Shadow has written.

```
    SET @sql = 'select * from ( 
        (
         select *, @rank:=@rank+1 as x from `list_content` where `id` > @my_id order by `id`)
         union (select *, @rank:=@rank+1 as x from `list_content` where `id` < @my_id order by `id`)
        ) `list_content`
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @my_id:=24, @rank:=0) as init
    WHERE `listId` = 15 limit 4';
```

Comment: I have tried your answer and I just get another syntax error, I also cannot seem to define a new delimiter

Comment: first i see is a mistake from me (copy pate) to set the vars use **:=** i have change it in my answer

Comment: Thanks for helping i appreciate it. I have made the code change and i just get another syntax error - MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//
CREATE PROCEDURE test
BEGIN
SET @sql = 'select * from ( 
        (
     ' at line 1

Comment: please post your hole store proc

Comment: delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE test
BEGIN
SET @sql = 'select * from ( 
        (
         select *, @rank:=@rank+1 as x from `list_content` where `id` > @my_id order by `id`)
         union (select *, @rank:=@rank+1 as x from `list_content` where `id` < @my_id order by `id`)
        ) `list_content`
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @my_id:=24, @rank:=0) as init
    WHERE `listId` = 15 limit 4';

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END//

Comment: see the samples here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html

Comment: I have been reading it, I still cannot see what I am missing. I can write simple sprocs and they work but i just cannot get this union  query to work.